# Calculate theoretically available quantity of a BOM item

Tags: sql, join

For a project I'm working on, I need to be able to communicate the quantity available to 'make' for a BOM item based on its contents. I won't go in-depth as to how this will be communicated, the base is in the SQL query.

The idea is fairly simple;
a BOM (Bill Of Material, indicating that it requires to be created) item (let's call this BOM1) has 1 or more stockitems linked to it. Having a quantity of 1 or higher. In this example let's take ITEM1 (3 units) ITEM2 (2 units) and ITEM3(5 units). Naturally, all of this is stored in a single table for referencing;

[image: Example table]

Secondary to that, there's the quantity in stock for each part within that BOM. this is stored in a 'bin content' table, example as below;

[image: bin content table]

The sum of the stock, per item, is then summarised as below;

[image: total stock per item]

Now, based on the 'contribution' of each item to the BOM item, you can calculate the maximum available number to create;

[image: Available to make per part]

in this scenario, based on ITEM3, I can create a maximum of 8 of item BOM1 as this has the lowest contribution (for lack of a better word I guess). Let's assume that parts can only be used once for a BOM item.

I can create a query for a single BOM item using a TOP 1 and ORDER BY ASC statement, the problem is that I have multiple BOM items, each having its own parts with multiple bin locations;

```
select TOP 1
BOM_ITEM.ITEM_NO
, (SUM(BIN_CONTENT.QTY) / BOM_ITEM.PART_ITEM_QTY) as AVAIL_TO_MAKE


from BOM_ITEM
    JOIN BIN_CONTENT
    ON BOM_ITEM.PART_ITEM_NO = BIN_CONTENT.ITEM_NO

WHERE BOM_ITEM.ITEM_NO = 'BOM1'

GROUP BY 
BOM_ITEM.ITEM_NO

ORDER BY AVAIL_TO_MAKE ASC
```

So, based on the BOM item, I want to retrieve only the part item qty with the lowest 'contribution' so to communicate the theoretically available quantity to make, I just can't figure it out though.

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Additionally, I suggest removing the "microsoft-dynamics" tag. Possibly, you will run the query in Dynamics. But the question itself is a pure SQL question.

Comment: Is this Dynamics NAV/Business Central? If you are doing this in NAV/BC I don't see a reason you'd write this as a SQL query - use the codeunits that already exist to calculate availability. If this needs to be exposed outside of NAV/BC, publish a web service that can do this and consume it. It will be very difficult to get the same answer from SQL as there's a lot of stuff that happens in NAV/BC to calculate availability - you have to consider supply/demand which may include reservations, put-aways not yet completed etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

The below query computes for each BOM item, how many items can be created given the available stock.

The query uses subquery to compute the stock across all bins. The main query groups by BOM item. For each BOM item, the minimum available to make is used. Additionally, the *floor* function is used to round down to an integer value.

```
WITH STOCK
USING (
    SELECT ITEM_NO, SUM(QTY) AS QTY
    FROM BIN_CONTENT
    GROUP BY ITEM_NO
)
SELECT BOM_ITEM.ITEM_NO AS BOM_ITEM_NO,
    FLOOR(MIN(STOCK.QTY / BOM_ITEM.PART_ITEM_QTY)) AS AVAIL_TO_MAKE
FROM BOM_ITEM
JOIN STOCK ON STOCK.ITEM_NO = BOM_ITEM.ITEM_NO
GROUP BY BOM_ITEM.ITEM_NO
```